# How to merge to rows into a single row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a query which does a union operation. This is the query

```
SELECT R.ThanaID, R.RoadTypeId, Count(R.Id) AS NoRdExist, 0 AS NoRdImp, 0 AS 
BcLenExist, 0 AS BcLenImp FROM RoadInventory AS R 
        INNER JOIN Thana AS A ON R.ThanaID = A.Id GROUP BY R.ThanaID,R.RoadTypeId 

UNION SELECT R.ThanaID, R.RoadTypeId, 0 AS NoRdExist, Count(R.Id) AS 
NoRdImp,0 AS BcLenExist, 0 AS BcLenImp FROM RoadInventory_Temp AS R
        INNER JOIN Thana AS A ON R.ThanaID = A.Id GROUP BY R.ThanaID, R.RoadTypeId 

UNION SELECT R.ThanaID, RI.RoadTypeId, 0 AS NoRdExist, 0 AS NoRdImp, 
Sum(CASE WHEN(R.SurfaceType='BC') THEN ((R.ToChain-R.FromChain)/1000) END) 
AS BcLenExist, 0 AS BcLenImp
    FROM (RoadInventory AS RI 
        INNER JOIN Thana AS A ON RI.ThanaID = A.Id) 
        INNER JOIN Segment AS R ON (RI.Id = R.RoadID) AND (RI.ThanaID = R.ThanaID) GROUP BY R.ThanaID, RI.RoadTypeId 

UNION SELECT R.ThanaID, RI.RoadTypeId, 0 AS NoRdExist, 0 AS NoRdImp, 0 AS 
BcLenExist, Sum(CASE WHEN(R.SurfaceType='BC') THEN ((R.ToChain-R.FromChain)/1000) END) 
AS BcLenImp
    FROM (RoadInventory_Temp AS RI 
        INNER JOIN Thana AS A ON RI.ThanaID = A.Id) 
        INNER JOIN Segment_Temp AS R ON (RI.Id = R.RoadID) AND (RI.ThanaID = R.ThanaID) GROUP BY R.ThanaID, RI.RoadTypeId
```

The result is Like this

```
ThanaID |RoadTypeId |NoRdExist |NoRdImp |BcLenExist |BcLenImp |
...............................................................
10101   |2          |0         |0       |0          |92
...............................................................
10101   |2          |0         |0       |92         |0
............................................................... 
10101   |2          |0         |8       |0          |0
...............................................................
10101   |2          |8         |0       |0          |0
............................................................... 
10101   |3          |0         |0       |0          |42
...............................................................
10101   |3          |0         |0       |42         |0
...............................................................
10101   |3          |0         |26      |0          |0
...............................................................
10101   |3          |26        |0       |0          |0
...............................................................
```

Now I want to merge the columns which contains 0(zero) into the columns containing value.Like This

```
ThanaID |RoadTypeId |NoRdExist |NoRdImp |BcLenExist |BcLenImp |
...............................................................
10101   |2          |8         |8       |92         |92
............................................................... 
10101   |3          |26        |26      |42         |42
...............................................................
```

How can I squeeze these rows?

Comment: I am not aware of your schema but a quick look at the query tells there is no need for union. You can perhaps implement this in single query with multiple joins. If not, wrap this union with another select with sum function on required columns.

Comment: Trivially, wrap your current query as a CTE and then aggregate by `ThanaID`, taking the sums of all the columns.  Or, go with the suggestion by @danish and try to write a single query to handle everything.

Comment: On a sidenote: Why `UNION` instead of a simple `UNION ALL`? I don't think there are any duplicates to remove, are there? Then why are you joining with the `Thana` table all the time? You are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

You want one result row per ThanaID and RoadTypeId with the sums of the other values. So based on the query you have you can simply aggregate:

```
select thanaid, roadtypeid, sum(nordexist), sum(nordimp), sum(bclenexist), sum(bclenimp)
from ( your query here )
group by thanaid, roadtypeid
order by thanaid, roadtypeid;
```

(I would probably have written the query differently so as not to get the values in separate rows, but with the query given above query is the easiest solution now.)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. Can you share how would you write this query? I cannot do SUM as I have some other columns which contains VARCHAR

Comment: Then your description and example are incomplete. It's not only zero and not zero and their sums as in your example. For strings you are probably just using nulls in place of zero (which you should have used for the numeric values, too), so you could just use `MAX(value` or `MIN(value)`. Anyway, I've posted another answer which avoids the unioned intermediate result altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You are running different queries per `ThanaID` and `RoadTypeId`. Then you combine them via `UNION`. It is not clear why you are doing this, because it seems you are not interested in that `UNION` result. It seems you want a joined result instead. Maybe inner joins, maybe a full outer join of all queries; which I don't know. Below I'm showing a result on all `ThanaID` and `RoadTypeId` combinations, thus avoiding a full outer join, because multiple full outer joins are rather clumsy in SQL Server for the lack of a `USING` clause.

```
select
  t.id as thanaid,
  rt.id as roadtypeid,
  q1.nordexist,
  q2.nordimp
from thana t
cross join roadtype rt
left join
(
  select thanaid, roadtypeid, count(*) as nordexist 
  from roadinventory 
  group by thanaid, roadtypeid 
) q1 on q1.thanaid = t.id and q1.roadtypeid = rt.id
left join
(
  select thanaid, roadtypeid, count(*) as nordimp
  from roadinventory_temp 
  group by thanaid, roadtypeid 
) q2 on q2.thanaid = t.id and q2.roadtypeid = rt.id
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi group by ThanaID and RoadTypeID then sum the field NoRdExist,NoRdImp,BcLenExist
and BcLenImp.
Try this

```
select  ThanaID ,RoadTypeId ,NoRdExist=sum(isnull(NoRdExist,0)),sum(isnull(NoRdImp,0) ) NoRdImp,sum(isnull(BcLenExist,0)  ) as BcLenExist,BcLenImp=sum(isnull(BcLenImp,0)   )  from (
SELECT R.ThanaID, R.RoadTypeId, Count(R.Id) AS NoRdExist, 0 AS NoRdImp, 0 AS 
BcLenExist, 0 AS BcLenImp FROM RoadInventory AS R 
        INNER JOIN Thana AS A ON R.ThanaID = A.Id GROUP BY R.ThanaID,R.RoadTypeId 

UNION SELECT R.ThanaID, R.RoadTypeId, 0 AS NoRdExist, Count(R.Id) AS 
NoRdImp,0 AS BcLenExist, 0 AS BcLenImp FROM RoadInventory_Temp AS R
        INNER JOIN Thana AS A ON R.ThanaID = A.Id GROUP BY R.ThanaID, R.RoadTypeId 

UNION SELECT R.ThanaID, RI.RoadTypeId, 0 AS NoRdExist, 0 AS NoRdImp, 
Sum(CASE WHEN(R.SurfaceType='BC') THEN ((R.ToChain-R.FromChain)/1000) END) 
AS BcLenExist, 0 AS BcLenImp
    FROM (RoadInventory AS RI 
        INNER JOIN Thana AS A ON RI.ThanaID = A.Id) 
        INNER JOIN Segment AS R ON (RI.Id = R.RoadID) AND (RI.ThanaID = R.ThanaID) GROUP BY R.ThanaID, RI.RoadTypeId 

UNION SELECT R.ThanaID, RI.RoadTypeId, 0 AS NoRdExist, 0 AS NoRdImp, 0 AS 
BcLenExist, Sum(CASE WHEN(R.SurfaceType='BC') THEN ((R.ToChain-R.FromChain)/1000) END) 
AS BcLenImp
    FROM (RoadInventory_Temp AS RI 
        INNER JOIN Thana AS A ON RI.ThanaID = A.Id) 
        INNER JOIN Segment_Temp AS R ON (RI.Id = R.RoadID) AND (RI.ThanaID = R.ThanaID) GROUP BY R.ThanaID, RI.RoadTypeId) as t
        group by ThanaID ,RoadTypeId
```